# ClassNotFoundException for kotlin application inside docker container

Tags: docker, kotlin, docker-compose

I have simple `kotlin` application which I am trying to `dockerise`.

Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.8.1-openjdk-17-slim  AS base
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "/root/.m2"

VOLUME "/root/.m2"

COPY ./. /

ADD entrypoint.sh .

ADD target/simulation-1.0.jar ./

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
java -cp "kotlin-stdlib.jar;simulation-1.0.jar" com.demo.app.simulation.Simulator
```

`Simulator.kt` has main method

When I am running docker-compose with Dockerfile I am getting

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.demo.app.simulation.Simulator

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.demo.app.simulation.Simulator
```

I am not sure what I am missing here. I am very new to `Kotlin` and `Docker`.

Comment: On Linux and other Unices, `java -cp` is usually a _colon_-separated path, `kotlin-stdlib.jar:simulation-1.0.jar`.  Does changing that separator fix this?

Comment: Hi David, I guess that solves the problem but now I am facing another issue for dependent jar. How to pass dependent jars while executing jar from commandline

Comment: if you are using gradle then use `shadowjar` plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution on this -

I use maven `assembly` plugin to build a `.jar`, move all my dependent jars into lib folder and run the command.

```
java -cp "lib\*:simulation-1.0.jar" com.demo.app.simulation.SimulatorKt
```